# What's the octave equivalent of eig(X, 'nobalance')

Tags: matlab, octave, markov-chains

I'm trying to find the equilibrium distribution of a markov chain, which means finding the eigenvalues of the transition matrix representing it, however, the eig function automatically normalises the eigenvectors it returns, in MatLab there is a flag you can pass to the function to stop this behaviour

> eig(X, 'nobalance')

Where X is a matrix. See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eig.html. However, when I try this in octave I just get an error:

> error: eig: wrong type argument `sq_string'

Is there some other function I should be calling?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to compute the equilibrium distribution of a Markov chain, take a look at the [mcStatDist](http://pmtk3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/toolbox/BasicModels/markov/sub/mcStatDist.m) function implementation from the [PMTK3 toolbox](http://code.google.com/p/pmtk3/). It shows four different ways to compute the result. Example:

```
TR = rand(3,3);                          %# random transition matrix
TR = bsxfun(@rdivide, TR, sum(TR,2));    %# normalize so that rows sum to one

[V,D] = eig(TR');                        %'# eigen-decomposition
EQ = V(:,1) ./ sum(V(:,1));              %# state equilibrium distribution
```

As noted in the comments of the linked code, this method can be numerically unstable for some cases, so you might want to consider one of the other options...